# Connect to another database in custom module

Tags: php, magento

I have created a new module **forumprodposts** in its config.xml file I have added the below xml. In controller I have added this code

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM comments";
$conn   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('forumprodposts_read');
$data   = $conn->fetchAll($sql);
```

But the above code throws error that comments is not a table of the core database. I think in my xml there is some mistake, so connection to the **prodcomments** database is not establishing.

```
<resources>
    <forumprodposts_write>
        <connection>
            <use>prodcomments_database</use>
        </connection>
    </forumprodposts_write>
    <forumprodposts_read>
        <connection>
            <use>prodcomments_database</use>
        </connection>
    </forumprodposts_read>
    <forumprodposts_setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </forumprodposts_setup>
    <forumprodposts_database>
        <connection>
            <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
            <username><![CDATA[username]]></username>
            <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
            <dbname><![CDATA[prodcomments]]></dbname>
            <model>mysql4</model>
            <type>pdo_mysql</type>
            <active>1</active>
        </connection>
    </forumprodposts_database>
</resources>
```

Comment: Try this <?php
  $resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $conn       = $resource->getConnection('external_database');
    $results    = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM tblName');
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($results);
   ?>

Answer (score 1):

You named the database resource `<forumprodposts_database>`, but tell your read/write handles to use `prodcomments_database` as resource. Changing the `<use>` nodes from:

```
<use>prodcomments_database</use>
```

to

```
<use>forumprodposts_database</use>
```

should fix this issue.